# How Do I Match Words That Start With Capital And Non Capital Letters?

Tags: c++, regex

I am trying to create a regex that will match a regular word like `cat` but also be able to match that word in different cases.

For example, if I have an expression `[Cc]at` the regex would match and I could use this in my program to search for files containing the string `cat` or `Cat`. But, if my expression is just simply `Cat` or `cat`, I still want to be able to regex match on this and search files for only that expression.

I have the first part matching I believe, but if there is some regex wizards out there that could explain how this is done, that'd be great!

Here's my attempt:

```
([^?][A-Z][a-z][^?]*)
```

...which will match `[Cc]at` but not `cat` or `Cat`.

Comment: I don't fully understand why `[Cc]at` is a non-satisfactory solution.

Comment: Instead of [A-Z][a-z] can you try [A-Za-z]

Comment: @orlp [Cc]at is a satisfactory solution but its only part of what I need to match on. I also want to just match words without the [] case brackets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're talking about case-insensitive matching.  It's enabled in a variety of ways, depending on the regex flavor and the context: as a postfix modifier (`/cat/i`); as an inline modifier (`"(?i)cat"`); as an option (`"i"`, `re.I`, `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE`, `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`, et al); or by checking the appropriate box, if you're using a graphical search/replace widget.

If you want to make *only* the first letter case-insensitive, there's no way to do that from outside the regex.  To match any word, which may start with an uppercase or lowercase letter but must contain only lowercase letters thereafter, you can use `[A-Za-z][a-z]*`.  Or the Unicode equivalent, `\p{Lu}\p{L}*`.

By the way, here's what your regex is doing:

```
([^?][A-Z][a-z][^?]*)
```

- The first `[^?]` matches the `[` (it means *any character except `?`*, which I'm guessing is not what you intended).
- `[A-Z]` matches the `C`.
- `[a-z]` matches the `c`.
- `[^?]*` matches the remainder.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use these, it will make all of the letters lower case and then you can compare it

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;

#include <string>
using std::string;

void toLowerCase(string &str)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
    {
        str[i] = (char)tolower(str[i]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    string str1 = "Cat";
    string str2 = "cAT";

    toLowerCase(str1);
    toLowerCase(str2);

    cout << (str1 == str2);

    cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```